# MS Access security (frontend vs. backend)

Tags: ms-access

If I have an MS Access frontend that connects to an MS Access backend, is there a way to hide/permission block the pathway to the backend's folder such that they cannot access the backend database without severing the frontend/backend connection?

Right now I can't dedicate a server to a more "secure" form of DB or anything like that so I'm stuck with MS Access for now. I just don't want someone looking at, say, a link table path and then navigating to that folder and getting access to backend information. What might be some solutions to this?

Comment: If you have people you cannot trust who have access to your server, I think you have quite a bit to worry about :)

Comment: I reckon the best you can hope for is to inconvenience them. Do your users need a full version of MS Access or would runtime suit? Have you compiled your front-end to an *.mde/accde with only your purpose built menus? Which version of MS Access are you using?

Comment: It's MS Access 2003 I believe. It's an .mdb file with some frontend forms that draw from queries/link tables/etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MS Access 2003 you can get some protection from [user-level security](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-user-level-security-mdb-HP003070410.aspx) Be very careful, the forums are full of people who have permanently lost access to their files. You should also create your own menus and compile. It is possible to disable the shiftkey open and all built-in menus, once again, this can lock you out of your file.

Comment: Mainly the problem is that they can see the backend folder if they looked hard enough for it. I want to be able to shut off access to the backend folder, and only allow access to that folder through the frontend db.

Comment: That is just not going to happen with MS Access, as I said, if they are that untrustworthy and have access to your server, you have quite a bit to worry about.

Comment: @AgainstASicilian Access 2003 as mentioned by Remou uses the "workgroup" .ldb security structure, by default an ldb (lock) file will be created in the directory of both the frontend mdb and if data is accessed then also in the directory of the backend mdb. If user's have no permissions on this folder then they receive an error as they are unable to write/remove entries from the lock file.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have mentioned it, but I highly recommend that you migrate the backend to SQLExpress. The security model is much better and safer to use. SQL Express does not require a dedicated server and performs well on the desktop.

Comment: I have just spent a considerable amount of time fixing an SQL Server Express permissions problem created by an install. SQL Server Express requires a much higher level of technical support than MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can password protect your backend file.